# How can I return JSON object list with Jersey/Jackson

Tags: json, list, jersey, jackson

I am using Jersey/Jackson for return object to JSON. 
I can return it successfully for single object but I can't return for list.

How do i return list object serialize to JSON

This is My Example

dependencies like this :

```
 <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

My model Like this :

```
public class Person {


private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}
public Person() {
    super();
}


@Override
public String toString() {


    return "Person [name="+ name +", surname="+ surname +", age="+ age +"]";
}
```

My Service Like this :

```
@Path("/getperson")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person getPerson(){

    Person person = new Person(name, surname, age);



    return person;

}


@Path("/getpersons")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Person> getPersons(){

    Person p1 = new Person("gosling", "james", 55);
    Person p2 = new Person("torvalds", "linus", 48);
    Person p3 = new Person("riche", "dennis", 60);

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(p1);
    persons.add(p2);
    persons.add(p3);

    return persons;


}
```

getPerson() work well but getpersons() returning empty.

Comment: <Hostname>/getpersons should fetch list of persons . You should not use <Hostname>/getPersons

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I am using glassfish jersey dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and lists do get returned almost as I would like with 0 configuration or mapping.
I don't see any particular issue in your code.